# How add the Video in Content Editor Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, 2007, sharepoint-server

I have task to add the video in Content Editor Web-part.Can any one help me how can I add the video in Content Editor Web-part

Answer (score 1):

For Flash videos I have created a similar solution using [Flowplayer](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/) and jQuery. You find the commplete solution for the Content Editor Web Part [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/creating-a-flash-video-player-for-sharepoint-using-the-built-in-web-parts-version-1/). Or you can use the Content Query Web Part as well, as described [here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/creating-a-flash-video-player-for-sharepoint-using-the-built-in-web-parts-version-2/). You should store the video files in a document library of SharePoint.

The bulk of the CEWP solution:

```
<script src="/_layouts/Flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" ></script >
<script src="/_layouts/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" ></script >
<script src="/_layouts/jQuery/json2.js" ></script >
<script src="/_layouts/jQuery/linq.js" ></script >
<script src="/_layouts/jQuery/linq.jquery.js" ></script >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/Flowplayer/style.css" >

<span >
  <a style="display:block;width:520px;height:330px" class="myPlayer" ></a >
</span >

<div class="videoList" style="text-align:left;" ></div > 

<script language="ecmascript" > 

function startClip(src, title)
{
  flowplayer().play([
    { url: src, title: title }
]);
}

$(document).ready(startScript);

function startScript()
{
  // initialize FlowPlayer in the 'myPlayer' anchor (A) HTML tag flowplayer("a.myPlayer", "/_layouts/Flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf");
  // ctx assumes a ListViewWebPart (it might be even hidden) on the same page var siteUrl = ctx.HttpRoot;
  // clear the video list DIV (videoList) $('.videoList').empty();
  $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            // get the (file)Name and Title property of each .FLV file
            url: siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/VideoLib1?$filter=endswith(Name,'.flv')&$select=Name,Title",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function (result) {
                var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
                if (response.error) {
                    alert("Error: " + response.error.code + "\n" + response.error.message.value);
                }
                else {
                    var videos = response.d.results;
                    Enumerable.from(videos).forEach(function (x) {
                        // on click event will be the video clip started
                        var link = '<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" title ="' + x.Name.substring(0, x.Name.length – 4) + '" onclick="startClip(\'' + x.__metadata.media_src + '\', \'' + x.Title + '\')">' + x.Title + '</a></p>';
                        // append video link to the video list DIV (videoList)
                        $('.videoList').append(link);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
}

</script >
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple ifrmae html tag to add video

```
<iframe src = "/_layouts/15/videoembedplayer.aspx?extSrc=/*<file path>*" type = "text/html" />
```

Comment: HI .The video is in some other URL,And the video is embedded in Silverlight